# Neo4j - Difference between Causal clustering and HA clustering

Tags: neo4j

We are thinking about installing Neo4j cluster with 3 nodes. 
But deciding between Causal and HA is where we are stuck.

Actually I couldn't get the difference between the two.

Any advice on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: this question has already been posted on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398197/neo4j-casual-clustering-benfit-over-ha  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652448/how-to-decide-between-neo4j-causal-vs-ha-clustering

Comment: Thanks I got the answer from the link you have given!